# How do i solve this discord.js problem i'm getting

Tags: discord, discord.js

I was creating a ticket bot for a discord server and i'm getting back the error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: category is not defined"
Sorry if this is a bit short. im using node version 12.18.4. Not sure what more i should add
This is my code, what did i do wrong?

```
        case "ticket":

                const reason = message.content.split(" ").splice(1).join("");
                
                let SupportCategory = message.guild.channels.cache.get(category => category.name === "Tickets")
    
                if (message.guild.me.hasPermission(`MANAGE_CHANNELS`) && !SupportCategory) {
                    SupportCategory = await message.guild.channels.create('Tickets', {
                        type: category,
                    })
                }
    
    
                if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(`MANAGE_CHANNELS`) && !SupportCategory) {
                    message.channel.send("I do not have permission to create the category needed for tickets.")
                
                }
    
                if (!message.guild.roles.cache.get(role => role.name === "Support Team")) {
                    await (message.guild.roles.create({
                        name: 'Support Team',
                        color: 'BLUE',
                    }));
                };
    
                let supportrole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(role => role.name === "Support Team")
    
                if (!supportrole) {
                    return message.channel.send("Sorry, but there is no Support Team role in this server.")
                }
    
                if (!reason) {
                    return message.channel.send("Please specify a ticket reason.")
                }
    
                const channelName = `ticket-${message.author.username}-${message.author.discriminator}`
                if (message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel => channel.name === `ticket-${message.author.username.toLowerCase}-${message.author.discriminator}`)) {
                    return message.channel.send("Sorry, but you already have a ticket open.")
        }
        
        message.guild.channels.create(channelName, { parent: SupportCategory.id, topic: `Ticket Owner: ${message.author.id}` }).then(c => {
            const sr = message.guild.roles.cache.get(supportrole)
            const everyone = message.guild.roles.cache.get(role => role.name === "@everyone")
            c.UpdateOverwrite(sr, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: true,
                VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
            });
            c.UpdateOverwrite(everyone, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
            });
          c.UpdateOverwrite(message,author, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: true,
                VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
            });
            let CreatedTicketEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("BLUE")
            .setTitle("New Support Ticket!")
            .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}> Your support ticket channel is <#${c.id}>`)
            .setFooter("RagePvP.")
            message.channel.send(CreatedTicketEmbed)
            let GreetEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("BLUE")
            .addField("New Ticket Ticket", `<@${message.author.id}> Thanks for opening a ticket. Help will be with you shortly.`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter("RagePvP.")
            c.send(GreetEmbed)
        }).catch(console.error);
    break;
```

Comment: You're using `Collection.get()` instead of `Collection.find()`. Just change the function name. Use `Collection.get()` to get an element by it's key (ID), and `.find()` when you need to find something by one of it's properties (for example, name)

Comment: What do you mean sorry? I changed it to let SupportCategory = message.guild.channels.cache.find(category => category.name === "Tickets") and still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have category, You need to put the slanted `` round category and it will work I tested it for you in my own bot works fine.

```
  if (message.guild.me.hasPermission(`MANAGE_CHANNELS`) && !SupportCategory) {
                    SupportCategory = await message.guild.channels.create('Tickets', {
                        type: `category`,
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update node to current. As far as your error, it seems in your

```
  let SupportCategory = message.guild.channels.cache.get(category => category.name === "Tickets")
```

Does "category" after message guild have a value? It doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? that's my full code for that command

Comment: message.guild.channels.cache.get(category =>
does that catergory havea value? Is it defined anywhere?